# O que significa [] em angular.module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-module

Sou iniciante em AngularJS e comecei a ler sobre módulos de uma aplicação. Quando eu desejo criar um novo módulo, escrevo a seguinte linha de código:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Pelo que entendi, o parâmetro `myApp` é o nome do módulo, mas nem na [documentação oficial](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) consegui entender o significado da lista vazia no segundo parâmetro. Pra que serve essa lista?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro é a lista de dependências do módulo que está sendo criado.

Traduzido para português da [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Os módulos podem listar outros módulos como suas dependências.
>   Dependendo de um módulo implica que o módulo necessário precisa ser
>   carregado antes que o módulo requerido seja carregado. Por outras
>   palavras, os blocos de configuração dos módulos necessários são
>   executados antes dos blocos de configuração do módulo requerente. O
>   mesmo é verdadeiro para os blocos de execução. Cada módulo só pode ser
>   carregado uma vez, mesmo que vários outros módulos o exijam.

### Exemplo carregando um service de configuração

```
angular.module('configService', []).value('parametros', {
    URI_PRODUCER: "http://meu_ip:8080/"
});
```

Outro módulo que carrega o serviço acima como dependência:

```
var app = angular.module('segundoModulo', ['configService']);
app.controller('meuController', function(parametros){
  console.log(parametros.URI_PRODUCER) // irá exibir http://meu_ip:8080
})
```

Answer (score 6):

É o conjunto de dependências deste módulo que está sendo criado.

Digamos que você crie seu módulo **myApp** e precise usar o mecanismo de rotas padrão do Angular.

Então, será necessário instalar o módulo (baixá-lo e referenciá-lo no projeto) e "injetá-lo" no seu módulo, desta forma

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

E isso é necessário para todo e qualquer módulo que for usado dentro de **myApp**.